# How do I get a numbered list in a List control?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a sub-report with a list object on it, showing a list of items that I would like to be numbered. I can get them to be bullet pointed and I had assumed that it would be as simple as changing it to numbering but when I do the numbers go 1., 1., 1., ... instead of 1., 2., 3., ...

Can someone help me get this working?

Comment: I've edited your question title, because I suspect this has nothing to do with the List Control being in a *subreport* or not. If you feel I have mistakenly edited your question feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **reason** this is happening is because you're probably setting the formatting on the *textbox inside the list*. A List itself doesn't allow you to set "Numbered List" formatting. The textbox always shows exactly 1 item, for each iteration in the List control.

There are two **ways around** to get what you want. The first option is to use an expression to show the number. The expression would be something like this:

```vb
=RowNumber("DataSet1") & ". " & Fields!MyListValue.Value
```

A second workaround (significantly more hackish!) may be to make a multi-valued hidden parameter, filled with default values from your dataset. You can then use a `Join` expression with newlines, place that inside a textbox, and set the Numbering format. Not tested though!

Answer (score 0):

This almost worked for me, but instead of using the DataSet in the paranthesis, I had to use the Tablix number. It may be because mine was in a subreport...not sure.

ex:

```
=RowNumber("Tablix1") & ". " & Fields!MapSourceName.Value
```